# Condition on map reduce counters to control the map output

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce, counter

Is there any chance to put a condition on user defined java counters at mapper level control the mapper output ??

```
       Long l = context.getCounter(Counters.COUNT).getValue();

        if(5L >= l) {
            context.getCounter(Counters.COUNT).increment(1);
            context.write((LongWritable)key, value);
        } else {
            System.out.println("MAP ELSE");
            return;
        }
```

getting more then five records input to the reducer.
Is there any chance to control this.???

Comment: Counter's value will only be know only when all the mapper's complete. How can you get the counter value in map side? What exactly is your requirement?

Comment: I am using user defined counter called Counters.COUNT. with help of this counter i want control my map output. regarding to control the mapoutput [ number of total mapoutput records is upto 5 ] . even have placed my context.write function call inside "if condition" but i am getting more then 5 records  from mapper as input to the reducer. So my intention is if that counter value reaches to MAX value (5) i want to treminate the map phase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot do that, if your input file has 3 splits then you will have 3 mappers running. Each mapper would have its individual count value(depends on the logic how to increment the count value) and that would only be known in the reduce side once all the mappers complete after the shuffle phase.

If you want to restrict your map output. Then have a single reducer `job.setNumReduceTasks(1)` and restrict the output from reducer. Something like this.

```
public static class WLReducer2 extends
        Reducer<IntWritable, Text, Text, IntWritable> {
    int count=0;
    @Override
    protected void reduce(IntWritable key, Iterable<Text> values,
            Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException {

        for (Text x : values) {
            if (count < 5)
            context.write(key, x);
            count++;
        }

    };
}
```

If you want to get the counter value in reduce side. You could add that to the reduce setup method.

```
 @Override
    public void setup(Context context) throws IOException, InterruptedException{
        Configuration conf = context.getConfiguration();
        Cluster cluster = new Cluster(conf);
        Job currentJob = cluster.getJob(context.getJobID());
        mapperCounter = currentJob.getCounters().findCounter(COUNTER_NAME).getValue();  
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer